# How to convert a UserControl into control

Tags: c#, type-conversion, user-controls, controls

I've created a program with a `Panel`, with a button I can add a `UserControl` in to the `Panel`. The `UserControl` contains only a `ComboList`

What I would like to do is to get all the UserControl in my `Panel` and get their value back.
I tried this but my program does not detect any ComboBoxes, so the table is empty:

```
private void button_add_outil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Récupère tous les élèves présents
            List<string> eleve = new List<string>();

            foreach (Control ctrl in panel_eleve.Controls)
            {

                if (ctrl is ComboBox)
                {
                    ComboBox c = ctrl as ComboBox;
                    eleve.Add(c.SelectedText);
                }
            }

            addOutil add_outil_window = new addOutil(eleve);
            add_outil_window.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Does anyone know how to convert a `UserControl` into a `Control` at the same time? Thank you.

Comment: A `UserControl` *is* a `Control`. [Look at the inheritance hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8). Is your question actually about recursively finding all controls nested in a parent control?

Comment: I think you'll find the ComboBoxes within the ctrl classes . You need to type check against your UserControl type first

Comment: I want to have access to the control that is in my UserControl
I tried to put it in Public, which worked because now I have access to it thanks to `userControl.ComboBox_eleve`but I get an error:the object reference is not defined to an instance of an object
 :(

Comment: What does the code look like where you get an error?

Comment: This is not a console error but an error with a window displayed

Comment: This addresses your problem: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pseudo code (and I'm assuming your `UserControl` is a container) but, as mentioned in my comment, I think you'll need to do something like the following:

```
        // Récupère tous les élèves présents
        List<string> eleve = new List<string>();

        foreach (Control ctrl in panel_eleve.Controls)
        {

            if (ctrl is UserControl) // You may be able to be more specific with this type
            {

                   foreach (Control innerControl in ctrl.Controls )
                   {
                       if (innerControl is ComboBox)
                       {
                            ComboBox c = innerControl as ComboBox;
                            eleve.Add(c.SelectedText);
                       }

                   }

            }
        }

        addOutil add_outil_window = new addOutil(eleve);
        add_outil_window.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I have already changed 
`foreach (Control innerControl in ctrl)`
on                                                                                                                      
  `foreach (Control innerControl in ctrl.Controls)`

But I get an error at 
`eleve.Add(c.SelectedText);`
The error is:
`the object reference is not defined to an instance of an object`

Comment: For clarity could you show what your code looks like now?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved
Here is the final code with some modifications

```
            foreach (Control ctrl in panel_eleve.Controls)
        {

            if (ctrl is UserControl_reponsable)
            {
                foreach (Control innerControl in ctrl.Controls)
                {                     
                    ComboBox c = innerControl as ComboBox;
                    eleve.Add(c.Text);
                }

            }
        }
```

Thank you very much!!